# How can i get frame.length in IE_DocumentComplete in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

How can I get frame.length in IE_DocumentComplete using vb.net 2013.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Private Doc As mshtml.HTMLDocument

    Private Sub IE_DocumentComplete(pDisp As Object, ByRef URL As Object) Handles IE.DocumentComplete
        Doc = IE.Document
        MsgBox(Doc.frames.length)  ' **System.InvalidCastException error here**
    End Sub

    Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer()
        IE.Visible = True

        IE.Navigate("https://www.google.co.jp")
        waitIE(IE)

   End Sub

    Private Sub waitIE(ByVal objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)
        Do Until objIE.ReadyState = SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or objIE.Busy = False
            Application.DoEvents()
            'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Loop

        Do While objIE.Document.ReadyState <> "complete"
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please edit your code format and be a little more specific in your question.

Comment: Hi,  Jonathan.  thanks for your comment!